# Stick gameObject after collision

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to develop a fishing game, I need to make the fish goes with the hook after they collide, I tried to do this by using this:

```
void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D collision) { 
    if(collision.gameObject.tag == "Hook") {
        transform.parent = collision.transform;
    }
}
```

But the fish keeps moving after the collision, however it goes up and down like the hook's movement. 
Can anyone help me, please?

Comment: I would include alot more code so we can help.

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the rigidbody of the fish, and/or set the fish to "kinematic" mode.

http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.html : see isKinematic and detectCollisions.